# Pure css toggle with no sibling

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, toggle, siblings

Using a checkbox for a css toggle, this code works...  The div disappears when you click the checkbox...

```
input:checked ~ #test{display:none}

<div id="main">
<input type="checkbox">Click Me
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
</div>
```

But here, it doesn't work, because the TEST div is not a sibling, right?  It's outside of the main div...

```
input:checked ~ #test{display:none}

<div id="main">
<input type="checkbox">Click Me
</div> 
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
```

Is there a way to make this work with just css?  I thought if I remove the ~ then any div with an ID = TEST would disappear no matter where it is, but that's not the case.

Comment: Nope....that's not possible. You can't select UP the DOM

Answer (score 0):

well this kind of works

the trigger is inside your main but the actual checkbox must be on the same level as "test"

```css
#main {white-space:nowrap;}
#check {
  display:none;
  }
p {display:inline-block;}
.fake{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background:lightgray;
  }
#check[type=checkbox]:checked + #main + #test {
  display:none;
  }
#check[type=checkbox]:checked + #main > label {
   background: gray;
}
```

```html
<input id="check" type="checkbox">
<div id="main">
  <label class="fake" for="check"></label>
  <p>Click Me</p>
</div> 
<div id="test">This is a test</div>
```